# Counting one's in a stream of bits

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis

I have to count the number of one's in last $m$ bits in a stream of bits and $m \leq n,$ where $n$ is the window size and it should take polylogarithmic space in $n$. I could only store last $n$ bits and then count the number of one's in those $n$ bits but it takes $O(n)$ space. How to achieve it in $O(\log^k n)$, $k>0$.
Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand your model. Can you explain it without using the word "window"?

Comment: Sliding window or tumbling window?

Comment: @Yuval Filmus Sir, I have given a bitstream, I have to count the number of 1's in the last $m$ bits of this bitstream.  Now, I have to take the most recent $n$ bits of this sequence of binary data where $n \geq m$ and now I have to count the number of 1's but it should take polylog space in $n$. Using Simple approach, I can do it in O(n) space to store bits and counting takes O(k) time but how to do it in polylog space. If possible, please help.

Comment: @6005, it is sliding window.

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't understand your model. You have an algorithm that reads bits from a bitstream in a streaming fashion (it gets them one by one, and cannot go back). You are only allowed to use a relatively small amount of space. At each point in time, you should be able to output the number of ones in the last $m$ bits read from the stream. Where does $n$ fit into all of that? Do you also have random access to the last $n$ bits of the stream? If so, you can easily maintain the number of ones in $O(\log m)$ time and space.

Comment: Do these slides answer your question? http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/mining/pdf/cs345-streams.pdf

Comment: @YuvalFilmus sir, I apologize. Maybe,  I have not explained the problem clearly.

Comment: @Dmitry sir, Thank you so much. It'll help. It is the same problem on page no. 10 which I was talking about.